# Can you make table read-only in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I have few big historical data tables in QuestDB and don't want to accidentally modify data in it.

Is there a way to make table locked or read-only in QuestDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have any security / permissions over the tables in QuestDB.

As a workaround however you can file system security and allow only read only access to the files in the table folders. Directory structure is very simple in QustDB

```
root/
       conf/
       db/
          tableA/
          tableB/
          ...
```